# HttpClient.PostAsync not complete with wrong DNS server , ios app frozen

Tags: xamarin.ios, httpclient, dotnet-httpclient, system.net.httpwebrequest

#### Steps to Reproduce

1. Setting wrong DNS at Ipad wifi setting (ex: 5.6.7.8)
2. Run App, Request HttpClient.PostAsync
3. App Frozen

#### Expected Behavior

Response Error in Catch()

#### Actual Behavior

App Frozen

#### Environment

Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019
Version 16.5.2
Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK   13.16.0.11
Ipad Ios 12, 13, 14
System.Net.Http 4.3.4

I have a Xamarin.Ios application, which has a function that uses HttpClient.PostAsync
In case the Ipad is setting DNS correctly, the app works normally, no problem
However, when the DNS setting is wrong, the app will freeze, when running to handle HttpClient.PostAsync

At the output, I'm seeing that Task PostAsync cannot be completed (for a long time there is still no error at Catch())

I have tried on many different devices
and also try on different versions of System.Net
But still can't solve

Comment: please highligh if it's code

Comment: I've also seen this happen. It looks like there's an open issue here: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/14545

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you are running that command on the UI thread. In that case that is expected to happen. As such you need to start the process on a new thread using `System.Tasks.Task.Run`.